# Determining significance with only two datapoints

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, experiment-design

I have data points on a selected group of users from Janurary. I have the percentage of male and female users, and percentage of their activity (example: 30% active, 70% inactive, not gender specific). I also have data points on a randomly selected group of users, of which I also have the same information (Janurary male/female, active/inactive percentage).

Is there a way to determine if the differences between my selected group of users and my randomly selected user group of users is statistically significant using only the data points I have?

I understand the typical way of doing this is to collect multiple months worth of data, calculate the standards deviation and see how many standard deviations away my selected group is. But I only have January data as of now, so I was wondering if there's anything I can do.

Comment: Maybe you have some simila, historic data you can use to guess standard deviations?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Ah unfortunately, I just started collecting data and only have January data. I also didn't collect daily breakdowns - I have to get better at my data collection process!